# change original view priority odoo 11

Tags: odoo-11

How to change the priority of an original view

I have tried to redefine the view by changing priority but didn't working:

```
<field name="priority">13</field>
```

Have an idea how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

< field name="priority" eval="13"/>